# Manage dependencies of ionic project - Github

Tags: github, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic project which needs to be shared with multiple developers using Github. We are not syncing the following folders to github, so they are part of the .gitignore file

plugins/

www/lib/

How would a new developer (who gets the app from github) would manage the dependencies that are part of these folders.

If I do 'ionic state restore' from the terminal then it fetches all the cordova plugins that are part of package.json. So, this takes care of the 'plugins/' folder.

However, www/lib folder is still empty. What do I need to do to get all the ionic/angular related javascript files that reside in the www/lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming the you have both bower and npm installed, if not follow these links to get your setup done: [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node), [bower](https://bower.io/#install-bower))

Ionic uses `bower` as its library package manager. Run these commands after you clone the project from github:

- `npm install` (refers `package.json` to install plugins)
- `bower install` (referes `bower.json` to install libs)

Hope it was helpful, Happy coding. :)